# IPhone app as a web server, any advice?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I've seen several programs that do this so that one could copy files (that are generated on the iphone via some app) back to the PC. They do this by making the iphone app run as a web server that gives you an ip address. You just connect to this ip via some browser and then you have links to the files.

What I'm wondering is how are they doing this, what kind of libraries (if any) are they using?? Does the iphone sdk have an easy way to do this?

Thanks!!

p.s is this web server idea the best way to transfer files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might start with this [simple HTTP server](http://culturedcode.com/cocoa/) written for Cocoa. More discussion on that [here](http://onlamp.com/pub/a/mac/2006/11/14/how-to-write-a-cocoa-web-server.html) by the author.

There's also [cocoahttpserver](http://code.google.com/p/cocoahttpserver/).