# Web services in iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, web-services, ipad

I have made one application for consuming web service using SOAP protocol on iOS device. Now i want to create such a application in which my iOS device should work as a web server for other devices.Is this possible ? if possible please give some guidelines or links to do this.

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com/) so far?

Comment: i have just made a application for consuming web services as stated.Now i will try for the web server application.

Comment: I mean, what did you try to implement the web server? Have you read any tutorials, have you [searched previous Stack Overflow answers](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=iphone+web+server)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

implementing web server as an iPhone app is explained in http://culturedcode.com/cocoa/ please refer to it
Also please refer to the answer to this question
[IPhone app as a web server, any advice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221027/iphone-app-as-a-web-server-any-advice)